# Parameters check responsibility between caller and called?

Tags: design-patterns, programming-languages, methods, call

Speaking generally, is the **caller** that should guarantee to pass well-formed data to the called method (thus the called method assume that data is always valid) or is the **called** method that should carry the data validation? What are pros and cons of each approach?

```
this.data = user.input;

// Caller check data
if (!this.data) throw new Exception("Data cannot be null.");
obj.consume(this.data);

public void consume(data)
{
   // Called check data
   if (!data) throw new Exception("data cannot be null.");
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**External-facing** (public, protected, exported, etc.) methods should validate their input, since they could be called by unknown future callers. For **internal-facing** (private, internal, inner, etc.) methods this is not necessary, as the caller is under your control and can be assumed to know what it's doing.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, each public method should validate it's inputs as a unit:

```
public Output Method1(Input1 input1, Input2 input2)
{
  if(input1 == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("input1");
  if(input1 == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException("input2");
  // ...
}
```

you keep validating in each layer and through exceptions and each layer decides whether to handle that exception or leave it to be thrown to the next layer.

Comment: And what good does *this* do - when you reference `input1` then it is going to throw anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The question can not be geneally answered. As you see two people here already have different ideas. (I for my part disagree that every public method needs to check their arguments ...) So when to check: if your method gets fed with external data, e.g. via a REST request. That means all methods on a service layer level need to check their arguments, and it does absolutely not matter if such methods are public or package access or protected. On private methods I would do the same, unless I'm 100% certain that some one else did that check on a higher level already.

OTOH if I craft a "library" then I can as well specify in the documentation: make sure all given parameters are correct, the library does not perform parameter checking.
E.g. I have a library for matrix and vector calculations, I certainly DON'T perform an "vec != null" and "mat != null) in every method making calculations with them. I also definitley DON'T make vec.length() == mat.height() tests. If at all, I use assertions for that. (See e.g. classic C string manipulation).

So, if you now would need a more save library, no one prevents you to write a wrapper method for every operation in the library to make such a check.

However, in an environment where you have to make objects persitent, you might want to take care that their internal state is "correct". So you might want to have stricter argument handling. However here again you can not simple decide: all publics make checks, all privates not. However again, as a developer team you could decide: we allways do it like this as we see a certain value in it (perhaps avoiding bugs in unit testing code).